# Finding factorial of factorial up to K times

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given N and K we need to find the value of

```
Fact(Fact(Fact(......Fact(N)....))) k times.
```

where Fact(N) = 1 * 2 * 3 *..... * (N-1) * N.

Means  if k=2, we have to calculate the value of Fact(Fact(N)) and so on.

We need to find the value mod 107.

So like if N=3 and K=2 then the answer is 78 as:

```
Fact(Fact(3))=Fact(6)=720.
720 % 107=78. So, answer is 78.
```

How to do it? Please help.

Code:

```
long long int fact(long long  int n){
    if(n==0)
       return 0;
    if(n==1)
       return 1;
    if(n>=107)
       return 0;
    else
       return mulmod(n,fact(n-1),107);  
}
```

In main:

```
int n,k,c=0;
cin>>n>>k;
long long  int ans=fact(n);
c++;
while(c<k){
    ans=fact(ans);
    c++;
}
```

For multiplication:

```
long long mulmod( long long  a, long long  b, long long  c){
long long x = 0,y=a%c;
while(b > 0){
    if(b%2 == 1){
        x = (x+y)%c;
    }
    y = (y*2)%c;
    b /= 2;
}
return x%c;
}
```

Comment: and what's the problem?

Comment: @MitchWheat I want to ask if am in right direction ?Because its providing wrong answers at some test cases

Comment: if test cases are failing then of course it's wrong! Possibly due to overflow...

Comment: @MitchWheat How overflow i used a different approach for multiplication too.But still the same

Comment: From the description alone I thought you need to do mod 107 *after* the fact(fact(...fact(n))) but in your code your impl of fact does mod at each computation. BTW you probably want to use arbitrary precision integer arithmetic for this (long long is not long enough)

Comment: @Brandin I used unsigned long long too.But it does not help

Comment: unsigned long long is not long enough either. arbtirary precision means arbitrary. also called BigNum or BigInt or whatever

Comment: @Brandin I dont think it will be required.

Comment: it depends on value of n and k, and on whether mod has to be done at each step or at the end. if you know so much why you here asking questionss??

Comment: Is this by any chance a HackerRank challenge? I'll give you a big hint: try working out 110! mod 107 on paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realize that if N >= 107, then N! is divisible by 107.

Thus you only need to worry about few values of N and K.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, that's not how you do a recursive factorial. Below is one that keeps up with the modulo for you.

```
long long int fact(long long int n, long long int modBy) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1; // remember, 0 factorial is actually 1
    return (n * fact(n - 1, modBy)) % modBy;
}
```

But since you're taking factorials of factorials, to a depth `k`, you could make a recursive wrapper around that that counts the depth.

```
long long int factfact(long long int n, long long int k, long long int modBy) {
    if (k < 1) return n; // no depth left
    return fact(factfact(n, k - 1, modBy), modBy);
}
```

Also I don't have a good feeling about these `long long int` variables, when they all are staying positive...personally I would `typedef unsigned long long ULL;` to ease my qualms and avoid typing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which is theoretically correct, but the number is just too big for it to calculate. The result for N = 3, K = 3 runs in 1000 to 2000 digits

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int len;
long Fact(long f){
    if (len == 1){
        long res = 1;
        for (long i = 1; i <= f; i++){
            res *= i;
        }
        return res;
    }
    if (len > 1){
        len--;
        long res = 1;
        long up = Fact(f);
        for (long i = 1; i <= up; i++){
            res *= i;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
int main(){
    long num;
    cout << "\nEnter N: ";
    cin >> num;
    cout << "\nEnter K: ";
    cin >> len;
    cout << endl << len;
    cout << "\nRecursive Factorial is: " << Fact(num) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'd suggest using some big integer libraries as a single result from N = 3 and K = 3 would be about 800 Bytes in size.

The answer for 720! is 2.601218943565795100204903227081e+1746 (calculated by Windows calculator) That's 1746 digits!! You couldn't expect any normal data type to handle that kind of a number (No long long wouldn't help)

Comment: Where is the 'modulo 107'?

Comment: If your numbers are getting that big, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I didn't add that as it doesn't really matter. It won't calculate with or without it for N=3, K=3 or higher.

Comment: @Beta: Try it, Fact(Fact(Fact(3))): Fact(3)=6, Fact(6)=720, Fact(720)= ~2000 digits

Comment: All right, I'll try it *with a pencil on the back of an envelope...* The answer is 0. It took me 19 seconds, and I spent most of that time looking for a pencil.

Comment: I'd really like to know what method you're using because you're wrong

Comment: How do you know I'm wrong if you can't calculate the answer?

Comment: open up the calculator in scientific mode, enter 720, hit n!, and you get 2.601218943565795100204903227081e+1746. That's 1746 digits

Comment: Now take modulo 107. [drum roll]

Comment: That's the point!! You NEED to Know the full answer to find the modulo. Try finding the modulo of 2.601218943565795100204903227081e+1746

Comment: I don't know how to say this any more clearly. The answer is zero. 720! mod 107 = 0. You don't know how I reached that conclusion, and you seem to have reached the conclusion that my answer is wrong by faulty intuition. I *DON'T* need to write out 720! to find the answer, because **I'm good at mathematics.** Take modulo 107 and post your answer, or admit that you can't and that you don't know whether I'm right or wrong. Do either of those, and then if you like I'll show you the method. Otherwise I won't discuss this with you any further.

Comment: Yeah, the answer is 0 (never argued that). Its pretty obvious. But I was talking about the factorial part. You could add the special condition for >=107, but that just made the question pointless, because everything after 107 is just 0. That's why I preferred addressing the main problem with this question which is that the factorials are getting too large to compute, and It'd be more interesting to make a Big integer object type with its own overloaded operators and stuff and work on the calculation. Right now its just like saying calculate the largest prime and show its product with 0.

Comment: This question is pointless, and that's what I was addressing here. and that's what the very first answer on this question also said.